# SpriteBatch - SharpDX Toolkit - Bezier Curves

Tags: c#, .net, rendering, sharpdx

I'm new to the DirectX development realm.  I'm using SharpDX's Toolkit for its abstraction of a Game, because it seems to simplify a lot of the initialization work.

I've been having difficulty finding good tutorials on this (if they're out there, I'm game, no pun intended.)

I'm trying to determine how to Draw Bezier Curves, lines, rectangles, and such along with a standard SpriteBatch.

Here's what I do know:

1. I need to use Path Geometries to construct the primitives to render the scene.
2. I need a render target to draw it to, but I can't seem to determine how to do that within the framework, and how to determine where it will end up being drawn.

Once I know this, how do I specify the render priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the ToolKit package through Nuget has been deprecated, and according to the github repository for it, it's in a non-working state when you upgrade everything to the latest versions.

There's type-collisions between `SharpDX.Direct2D1` and `SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics`.

Seems it's back to the drawing board on this one.  I think the biggest snafu with this is SharpDX simplifies a lot of the COM interop transparently.  The D2D1 class exposes the method (which is akin to the C++ method of the same, if you're reading a C++ tutorial):

```
CreateFactory(FactoryType factoryType, Guid riid, FactoryOptions? factoryOptionsRef, out IntPtr iFactoryOut)
```

However, you can just do `new Factory(...)` and it handles the call itself.

`Factory` leads to a `RenderTarget` which leads to a `GeometrySink` which leads to a `PathGeometry` which is then needed for rendering Beziers and such.  Haven't figured how to get anything on screen, but I'm closer!